# App Keeps Force Closing with Google Cloud Messaging on Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I'm in the process of making my own Android app and along the way discovered GCM (Google Cloud Messaging). I followed the following tutorial exactly: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/

The good news is that almost everything works properly, except that every time I send a push notification, the App force closes on the device. I don't think anything is wrong with the Eclipse project and I'm running Android 4.2.2 on my device. There are no compilation errors. It is driving me nuts that I can't figure out why the App keeps force closing.

The code is exactly the same as what is listed in the above link. For reference, here is my logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.javapapers.android.GcmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.javapapers.android.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.javapapers.android-1.apk
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2428)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:151)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1358)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5285)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:126)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.javapapers.android.GcmBroadcastReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.javapapers.android-1.apk
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2423)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7261):        ... 11 more
W/GTalkService( 1430): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.javapapers.android (has extras) }
```

My manifest looks like the following:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<permission
    android:name="com.javapapers.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.javapapers.android.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.javapapers.android" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMNotificationIntentService" />
```

I'm at my wits end trying to figure out what is wrong, so any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: For future reference: Don't post almost 7000 lines of logcat in a pastebin link. I already edited the relevant parts into your question. The problem most likely is that you did not declare the `BroadcastReceiver` in your manifest.

Comment: Sorry, wasn't entirely sure what would be relevant (so posted everything), I'll keep it in mind for the future. As for declaring it, I updated the OP with the manifest file. It was declared as ".GcmBroadcastReceiver"

Answer (score 0):

What package is your `GcmBroadcastReceiver` located in?

When using the `.` prefix, like you did when declaring `.GcmBroadcastReceiver`, the `.` translates to your package name. So unless `GcmBroadcastReceiver` is located in `com.javapapers.android` then it will not work.

Comment: Just to be sure, I went back into the project to make sure. The "GcmBroadcastReceiver" is located in the com.javapapers.android package, so everything should be okay. I went on ahead and changed ".GcmBroadcastReceiver" in the manifest to "com.javapapers.android.GcmBroadcastReceiver" however it didn't make a difference when running the app. Still force closes.

Comment: I just realized one thing. I am referencing Google APIs [Android 4.3] when I am using an Android 4.2.2 device. Should I try changing it? The thing is, no one mentioned a similar problem on the tutorial I followed (link in OP). I'm worried that things might get even more messed up if I change the Google APIs reference.

Comment: Edit: Okay, tried changing the version of Google APIs down to 4.2.2. App still force closes.

Answer (score 0):

Even I faced same concern. Right Click project go to -> build Path -> Config Build path -> order and export -> check mark Android dependencies (google paly services.jar) shift to top. Now Clean and build and run your application.